# a brother/sister of mine - one of my brothers/sisters

Tags: possessive-determiners

I have been told by native speakers that "a brother/sister of mine" is almost never used except in poems or old literature and should therefore always be "one of my brothers/sisters".
Is it a valid opinion?

I have found a few example, though.

1) A sister of mine had a ‘big’ birthday last week and I wanted to make a special card for her >     Fancy Fold Card with Bouquet Blooms ( Annette Sullivan: Independent Stampin' Up!® Demonstrator, Australia – )

2) Can a sister of mine, who is a lawyer, go to jail for filing a false police report about me in March of 2019? >     https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/can-a-sister-of-mine--who-is-a-lawyer--go-to-jail--4442448.html > (Highland Park, IL)> >

3) a sister of mine came down with polio >     https://www.parliament.wa.gov.au/Ha...3D6351C7D048256602000FB1A7/$file/C1125008.PDF > (australia)

What do you think of it?

Comment: As an only child I don't have occasion to say such a thing, but my feeling is that 'a sister of mine' is more anonymous. You might say it when speaking to people who don't know your sister and don't need to; you are just using her as an example. 'My sister' feels more personal.

Comment: but the question is "what's the difference between "a sister of mine" and "one of my sisters"?

Comment: The same applies to 'one of my sisters', if you have several, as to 'my sister'.

Comment: Two ways to say it.  There’s really no difference.

Comment: [GoogleNgrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+brother+of+mine%2Ca+sister+of+mine%2Cone+of+my+brothers%2Cone+of+my+sisters&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20brother%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20sister%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20my%20brothers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20my%20sisters%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20brother%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20sister%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20my%20brothers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20my%20sisters%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that your informants were perhaps too ...

Comment: prescriptive with ' ... should therefore **always** be ...', but that they nevertheless have a point.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I expect that it depends on the dialect, and there may be some dialects where people don't actually use "a sister of mine".

Comment: Certainly "a friend of mine" sounds a lot more likely than "one of my friends."

Comment: @Casey There I don't agree. 'A friend of mine' certainly sounds a lot more natural to my ears than 'a brother of mine', though.

Answer (score 1):

A “something” of mine usually means it is one of many, and it doesn’t matter much which one. “A friend of mine had his bicycle stolen”, “a teacher of mine came to school wearing non-matching sox”.

My “something” is much more specific. Like “my maths teacher”. It is  unusual to say “a sister of mine” unless you have at least eight sisters.

Answer (score 0):

It has the feel of active versus passive voice.

"My sister" or "One of my sisters" is more direct and therefore stronger.

Comment: Hello, gorlux. I think you make a valid point, but without supporting evidence, this has 'comment' status.

Comment: I don't agree with this. The "of mine" choice, if anything, emphasizes the "mine" part. Compare "my child will not attend" and "no child of mine will attend."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can consult [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20brother%20of%20mine%2Cone%20of%20my%20brothers&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image: graphs]

It seems "one of my brothers" is the common expression; "a brother of mine" is used, but it is unusual.